# Instantiateviewcontrollerwithidenfier don't find storyboard on Apple

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In my simulator works fine but when it goes to apple connect it can't find the storyboard. Anyone with the same problem?

Comment: please post your code. It may also be an issue that during an archive (for some reason) one of your storyboards is not being copied over. You can look at the build phases and check the copy resources step to see is one of your storyboards not checked

Comment: I created an ad hoc version and it worked, I don't understand what is failing

Comment: The exception it throws is "could not load the scene view controller for identifier"